# Build one hash from an array of many hashes using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array-of-hashes:

```
[{:key=>"RepositoryKey", :value=>"6958127"}, 
{:key=>"Guid", :value=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337"}, 
{:key=>"Association_Guid", :value=>"05500000-93ba-4898-8308-444a25df7eb6"},
{:key=>"Association_Type", :value=>"Association"},
{:key=>"Association_Name", :value=>"Hancock Wellness Center"}, 
{:key=>"Image_Guid", :value=>nil}, 
{:key=>"Image_Type", :value=>"StoredFile"}]
```

This comes from an external source, and I need to combine certain values into one single hash. For example, I want `RepositoryKey`, `Guid`, and `Association_Type` from the above array. I want something like this in the end:

```
hash = {"RepositoryKey" => "6958127", 
        "Guid" => "006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337", 
        "Association_Type" => "Association"}
```

What's the best way for me to do that using Ruby 2.0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## If you want some specific items from the array, then as below :

```
array_of_hash = [
         {:key=>"RepositoryKey", :value=>"6958127"}, 
         {:key=>"Guid", :value=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337"}, 
         {:key=>"Association_Guid", :value=>"05500000-93ba-4898-8308-444a25df7eb6"},
         {:key=>"Association_Type", :value=>"Association"},
         {:key=>"Association_Name", :value=>"Hancock Wellness Center"}, 
         {:key=>"Image_Guid", :value=>nil}, 
         {:key=>"Image_Type", :value=>"StoredFile"}
       ]

array = ["RepositoryKey", "Guid", "Association_Type"]

Hash[array_of_hash.select { |h| array.include?(h[:key]) }.map(&:values)]
# => {"RepositoryKey"=>"6958127",
#     "Guid"=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337",
#     "Association_Type"=>"Association"}
```

## If you want full hash

```
Hash[array_of_hash.map(&:values)]
# => {"RepositoryKey"=>"6958127",
#     "Guid"=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337",
#     "Association_Guid"=>"05500000-93ba-4898-8308-444a25df7eb6",
#     "Association_Type"=>"Association",
#     "Association_Name"=>"Hancock Wellness Center",
#     "Image_Guid"=>nil,
#     "Image_Type"=>"StoredFile"}
```

If you are in Ruby 2.1 version

```
array_of_hash.map(&:values).to_h
```

Bonus :

If each *inner hash* has more keys than the examples one, and you want to get the values of `:key` and `:value`, then write as below :

```
array_of_hash.map { |h| h.values_at(:key, :value) }.to_h
```

Comment: Yeah that's nice. What's not nice is having a variable named `hash` defining an Array ^_^ (kidding). Anyway he probably wants to create the big Hash at the start and work with that, especially if he needs to extract values more than once. +1

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Thanks for teaching when to give, what names to variables.. :-)

Comment: Instead of using `map` with a conditional, that results in an array containing a bunch of nils you have to `compact`, use `select` or `reject` to find the elements you want, then `map` them. Using `compact` after the fact is code smell.

Comment: @theTinMan That's a good. I also thought about it, but didn't write it as I though lots of intermediate array creation.. But your idea is 100% good and acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of earlier answers:

**Code**

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g[h.values.first] = h.values.last }
   .select { |k,_| target.include?(k) }
```

**Demo**

```
arr = [
         {:key=>"RepositoryKey", :value=>"6958127"}, 
         {:key=>"Guid", :value=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337"}, 
         {:key=>"Association_Guid", :value=>"05500000-93ba-4898-8308-444a25df7eb6"},
         {:key=>"Association_Type", :value=>"Association"},
         {:key=>"Association_Name", :value=>"Hancock Wellness Center"}, 
         {:key=>"Image_Guid", :value=>nil}, 
         {:key=>"Image_Type", :value=>"StoredFile"}
       ]

target = ["RepositoryKey", "Guid", "Association_Type"]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g[h.values.first] = h.values.last }
   .select { |k,_| target.include?(k) }
  #=> {"RepositoryKey"=>"6958127",
  #    "Guid"=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337",
  #    "Association_Type"=>"Association"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
array = [{:key=>"RepositoryKey", :value=>"6958127"}, 
         {:key=>"Guid", :value=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337"}, 
         {:key=>"Association_Guid", :value=>"05500000-93ba-4898-8308-444a25df7eb6"},
         {:key=>"Association_Type", :value=>"Association"},
         {:key=>"Association_Name", :value=>"Hancock Wellness Center"}, 
         {:key=>"Image_Guid", :value=>nil}, 
         {:key=>"Image_Type", :value=>"StoredFile"}]
hash = Hash[array.map{|h| [h[:key],h[:value]]}]
#=> {"RepositoryKey"=>"6958127", "Guid"=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337", "Association_Guid"=>"05500000-93ba-4898-8308-444a25df7eb6", "Association_Type"=>"Association", "Association_Name"=>"Hancock Wellness Center", "Image_Guid"=>nil, "Image_Type"=>"StoredFile"}
```

Best of both worlds full hash and you can reject the values you don't want later

```
wanted_values = ["RepositoryKey", "Guid", "Association_Type"]
hash.reject{|k,v| !wanted_values.include?(k)}
#=>{"RepositoryKey"=>"6958127", "Guid"=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337","Association_Type"=>"Association"}
hash
#=>=> {"RepositoryKey"=>"6958127", "Guid"=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337", "Association_Guid"=>"05500000-93ba-4898-8308-444a25df7eb6", "Association_Type"=>"Association", "Association_Name"=>"Hancock Wellness Center", "Image_Guid"=>nil, "Image_Type"=>"StoredFile"}
```

Comment: This has not been asked.. He want some items I think - *let's say I want RepositoryKey, Guid, and Association_Type from the above array.*..

Comment: `I want something like this in the end:` I think it has I think he may have just been limiting for brevity. Plus why deal with data destruction when he can have access to all the attributes needed and more if necessary

Comment: @engineersmnky valid point. I was planning to just select specific values, but it makes sense to just keep them in the case that I need them down the road.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_of_hash = [
         {:key=>"RepositoryKey", :value=>"6958127"}, 
         {:key=>"Guid", :value=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337"}, 
         {:key=>"Association_Guid", :value=>"05500000-93ba-4898-8308-444a25df7eb6"},
         {:key=>"Association_Type", :value=>"Association"},
         {:key=>"Association_Name", :value=>"Hancock Wellness Center"}, 
         {:key=>"Image_Guid", :value=>nil}, 
         {:key=>"Image_Type", :value=>"StoredFile"}
       ]

array = ["RepositoryKey", "Guid", "Association_Type"]

array_of_hash.select{|h| array.include? h[:key]}.map{|h| 
                     Hash[*h.values]}.reduce Hash.new, :merge
#=> {"RepositoryKey"=>"6958127", "Guid"=>"006444a2-3ea1-4b64-81b8-51ce4756d337", "As#ociation_Type"=>"Association"}
```